# Trouble editing color to bootstrap mobile friendly Nav-bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to edit my sites Mobile Friendly nav-bar but when i try edit it's CSS color it changes color to the regular nav-bar scrolling effect. I am trying to figure out how to edit change to colors to just the Mobile Friendly nav-bar only, Would anybody have any idea how that would be possible?

you can view the website: [Nav-bar Problem](https://palmist-absences-37165.bitballoon.com/)
and also view it from it's mobile size to get a better idea of what i am trying to do.

HTML:

```
html,
body {
background-color: #ccc;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

body {
font-family: Merriweather,'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

hr {
max-width: 50px;
border-color: #f05f40;
border-width: 3px;
    border-top: 0px;
}

hr.light {
border-color: #fff;
}

a {
color: #fff;
-webkit-transition: all .35s;
-moz-transition: all .35s;
transition: all .35s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
color: #eb3812;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Yellowtail', 'cursive';
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
}



.bg-primary {
        opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(231, 90, 144, 0.6) 0%, rgba(227, 89, 143, 0.81) 44%, rgb(221, 129, 164) 100%);
}

.bg-dark {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.text-faded {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

section {
    padding: 100px 0;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(70, 70, 90) 0%, rgb(70, 70, 90) 44%, rgb(127, 129, 136) 100%);

}

aside {
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}


.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color:  rgba(8, 13, 21, 0.3);
    opacity: .5;
}

.navbar-default {

    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;

    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #222;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
    color: #f05f40;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff!important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.collapse navbar-collapse a{
    background: #ccc;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background-color: transparent;
    }


    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-transform: none;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix {
    border-color: rgba(34,34,34,.05);
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(231, 90, 144) 0%, rgb(227, 89, 143) 44%, rgba(238, 64, 131, 0.760784) 100%);
    }


    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #46465A;
    }

  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a, .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #46465A;
}

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner hr {
    margin: 30px auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.section-heading {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.service-box {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    max-width: 400px;
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .service-box {
        margin: 20px auto 0;
    }
}

.service-box p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-box {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 650px;

}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(216, 27, 100, 0.51);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;

}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category,
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}

.call-to-action h2 {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.text-primary {
    color: #f05f40;
}

.no-gutter > [class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.btn-default {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    border-color: #ededed;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-default.disabled,
.btn-default[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,
.btn-default.disabled:hover,
.btn-default[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
.btn-default.disabled:focus,
.btn-default[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.disabled.focus,
.btn-default[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus,
.btn-default.disabled:active,
.btn-default[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
.btn-default.disabled.active,
.btn-default[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
    border-color: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-default .badge {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.btn-primary {
    border-color: #f05f40;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f05f40;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    border-color: #ed431f;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee4b28;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled.focus,
.btn-primary[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
    border-color: #f05f40;
    background-color: #f05f40;
}

.btn-primary .badge {
    color: #f05f40;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.btn-xl {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

::-moz-selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

img::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

body {
    webkit-tap-highlight-color: #222;
}

.fa-phone:before {
    content: "\f095";
    color: #fff;
  }

.fa-envelope-o:before {
    content: "\f003";
    color: #fff;
  }
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Merriweather,'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

hr {
    max-width: 50px;
    border-color: #f05f40;
    border-width: 3px;
        border-top: 0px;
}

hr.light {
    border-color: #fff;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Yellowtail', 'cursive';
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
}



.bg-primary {
        opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(231, 90, 144, 0.6) 0%, rgba(227, 89, 143, 0.81) 44%, rgb(221, 129, 164) 100%);
}

.bg-dark {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.text-faded {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

section {
    padding: 100px 0;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(70, 70, 90) 0%, rgb(70, 70, 90) 44%, rgb(127, 129, 136) 100%);

}

aside {
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}


.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color:  rgba(8, 13, 21, 0.3);
    opacity: .5;
}

.navbar-default {

    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;

    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #222;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
    color: #f05f40;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff!important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.collapse navbar-collapse a{
    background: #ccc;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background-color: transparent;
    }


    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-transform: none;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix {
    border-color: rgba(34,34,34,.05);
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(231, 90, 144) 0%, rgb(227, 89, 143) 44%, rgba(238, 64, 131, 0.760784) 100%);
    }


    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #46465A;
    }

  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a, .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #46465A;
}

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner hr {
    margin: 30px auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.section-heading {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.service-box {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    max-width: 400px;
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .service-box {
        margin: 20px auto 0;
    }
}

.service-box p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-box {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 650px;

}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(216, 27, 100, 0.51);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;

}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category,
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}

.call-to-action h2 {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.text-primary {
    color: #f05f40;
}

.no-gutter > [class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.btn-default {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    border-color: #ededed;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-default.disabled,
.btn-default[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,
.btn-default.disabled:hover,
.btn-default[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
.btn-default.disabled:focus,
.btn-default[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.disabled.focus,
.btn-default[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus,
.btn-default.disabled:active,
.btn-default[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
.btn-default.disabled.active,
.btn-default[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
    border-color: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-default .badge {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.btn-primary {
    border-color: #f05f40;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f05f40;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    border-color: #ed431f;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee4b28;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled.focus,
.btn-primary[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
    border-color: #f05f40;
    background-color: #f05f40;
}

.btn-primary .badge {
    color: #f05f40;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.btn-xl {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

::-moz-selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

img::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

body {
    webkit-tap-highlight-color: #222;
}

.fa-phone:before {
    content: "\f095";
    color: #fff;
}

.fa-envelope-o:before {
    content: "\f003";
    color: #fff;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you changing it after the media query?

Comment: I used my console and tried different classes that were linked to it, I think a couple of them were media queries. I was not sure how else to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since your CSS is bundled I'm not sure what file this property is in but changing the background-color with the snippet below allowed me to only change mobile:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Changed to:

```
.navbar-default {
        background-color: green;
        border-color: #e7e7e7;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome would you mind marking it as the answer please if you felt like it was?